# How to fix React invalid hook call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I just started leanring REACT and am following this youtube tutorial. I copied some code for an Appbar from material-ui's website but I'm getting these errors and I'm not sure how to fix them (I basically followed the youtube video exactly, and the guy in the video didn't get any errors).

This is my `App.js` file:

```javascript
import './App.css';
import AppBar from './AppBar';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <AppBar/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And this is my AppBar.js:

```javascript
import * as React from 'react';
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';

export default function ButtonAppBar() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            size="large"
            edge="start"
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="menu"
            sx={{ mr: 2 }}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" component="div" sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            News
          </Typography>
          <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

And these are the errors from chrome (the code does compile in vs code tho).
[image: Errors]

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: There are no hooks in your code. This is likely caused be 1) or 3) in the error output.

Comment: They're mentioned in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html) that it might be because the version of the **React** and the **React-dom**

Comment: There are no hooks in _your_ code. If you look at the last error it's coming from the `<Style>` component which I guess is in one of your imported components. As Amr mentions this might be because of the release of v18 of React which, if the owners of those components haven't made steps to make sure those components work, they will cause errors. v17.0.2 of React is probably the last release that will work properly.

Comment: guess I'll look up what a hook is lol

Comment: @Nathan just run this command **npm ls react-dom** to check the version of your react-dom. if react-dom (< 16.8.0) that doesn’t yet support Hooks. then this is why you get this error **Invalid Hooks**

Comment: @Amryasser Just ran it and mine is 18.2.0

Comment: @Nathan you still getting the same error?

Comment: @Amryasser Yeah I haven't been able to fix it... The error seemed to have occurred somewhere in the MUI files and I'm pretty new to react and I don't really know how to fix it.. I basically just got rid of all the MUI components and it works lol.

Comment: @Nathan enjoy :D